# Updating UITableViewCell subclass layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

If I have a `UITableViewCellSubclass` that can change layout depending if it's `TypeA` or `TypeB`.

Should I have an init that is `[UITableViewCellSubclass initWithType:type]` and whenever the type changes I call `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPath:indexPathForUITableViewCellSubclass]`

**OR**

I skip the custom init and implement `-layoutSubviews` and a `-setType:` and whenever I need to change the type of the cell I get a reference to the cell by calling `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` and then calling `[cell setType:TypeB]`

```
- (void)setType:(Type)type {

    if (type == _type) return;
    _type == type;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.type == TypeA) {
        CGRect frame = foo;
        thing.frame = frame;
    }

    if (self.type == TypeB) {
        CGRect frame = bar;
        thing.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I should clarify that the type change is not changing a whole lot actually. Just changing an image which indicates which type the cell is.

Comment: Why go through all that trouble?  Why not just create two different classes and dequeue the correct one in your CFIAP?  Have them inherit from a base class if they share a lot of functionality.

Comment: I should clarify that the type change is not changing a whole lot actually. Just changing an image which indicates which type the cell is.

Comment: I think subclassing is more appropriate here as suggested above - you need to hang the different code somewhere so why not do it in a tidy way?

Comment: The cell needs to know what type it is to draw/configure/setup the cell for the specific type. How would I set it up inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` depending if it should display `TypeA` or `TypeB`?